# Table and tablenotes go beyond tablewidth

Tags: tables, width

I created the following table:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}
 \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=30mm, right=30mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm]{geometry}

\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\small
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}
\caption{Descriptive statistics for hourly and minute returns of the timeseries.} \label{tab:title}
 \begin{tabular}{llllllllll[table-format=11.0]}
  \toprule
   & USDT & PAX & DGX & PAXG & DAI & WBTC & AMPL & BTC & LTC\\
   \hline
   \multicolumn{4}{l}{\textit{Panel A:1-hour returns}}
   \\
   Mean & -0.000 & -0.000 & 0.000 & -0.000 & -0.000 & 0.000 & -0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 \\ 
   Std.Dev & 0.000 & 0.005 & 0.033 & 0.004 & 0.000 & 0.040 & 0.018 & 0.010 & 0.015\\
  Min & -0.004 & -0.205 & -1.156 & -0.045 & -0.009 & -0.750 & -0.228 & -0.129 & -0.341\\
  Max & 0.005 & 0.114 & 0.906 & 0.030 & 0.008 & 0.583 & 0.107 & 0.117 & 0.168\\
  Skewness & 1.232 & -6.442 & -3.471 & -0.630 & -0.167 & -0.073 & -0.655 & -0.415 & -1.837\\
 Kurtosis & 44.684 & 396.572 & 356.572 & 12.145 & 21.741 & 45.938 & 9.759 & 12.355 & 41.134\\
 \hline
 \multicolumn{4}{l}{\textit{Panel B:1-minute returns}}
 \\
  Mean & -0.000 & 0.000 & -0.000 & -0.000 & -0.000 & -0.000 & -0.000 & -0.000 & -0.000\\
  Std.Dev & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.050 & 0.001 & 0.000 & 0.011 & 0.008 & 0.000 & 0.001\\
  Min & -0.000 & -0.005 & -2.200 & -0.013 & -0.002 & -0.038 & -0.118 & -0.012 & -0.012\\
  Max & 0.000 & 0.004 & 0.906 & 0.011 & 0.001 & 0.033 & 0.121 & 0.009 & 0.011\\
  Skewness & -0.000 & -0.436 & -13.229 & -0.137 & -0.071 & -0.033 & 0.155 & -0.122 & -0.095\\
  Kurtosis & 1.017 & 13.434 & 665.225 & 7.421 & 33.709 & -0.418 & 60.108 & 25.359 & 4.829\\
 \hline
 \multicolumn{9}{l}{\multirow{3}{*}{\scalebox{0.9}{\textit{Note: n = 6000      observations,Std.Dev is the standard deviation, Min and Max are the minimum and maximum of the timeseries. EUR/USD and JPY/USD are neglected because of...}}}}
 \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
```

Unfortunately the table goes a Little beyond the margins and the tablenotes go way beyond the pagewidth.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the missing packages. Also `\begin{tabular}{llllllllll[table-format=11.0]}` looks like it'll produce an error message.

Comment: Don't use `\scalebox` in tables unless you think your readers don't mind having to put up with wildly inconsistent font sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=30mm, right=30mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\footnotesize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}
\caption{Descriptive statistics for hourly and minute returns of the timeseries.} \label{tab:title}
 \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l
                              S[table-format=-2.3]
                              S[table-format=3.3]
                              S[table-format=3.3]
                              *{6}{S[table-format=-2.3]}@{}
                              }
  \toprule
   & {USDT} & {PAX} & {DGX} & {PAXG} & {DAI} & {WBTC} & {AMPL} & {BTC} & {LTC}\\
   \midrule
   \multicolumn{10}{l}{\textit{Panel A:1-hour returns}}
   \\
   Mean & -0.000 & -0.000 & 0.000 & -0.000 & -0.000 & 0.000 & -0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 \\ 
   Std.Dev & 0.000 & 0.005 & 0.033 & 0.004 & 0.000 & 0.040 & 0.018 & 0.010 & 0.015\\
  Min & -0.004 & -0.205 & -1.156 & -0.045 & -0.009 & -0.750 & -0.228 & -0.129 & -0.341\\
  Max & 0.005 & 0.114 & 0.906 & 0.030 & 0.008 & 0.583 & 0.107 & 0.117 & 0.168\\
  Skewness & 1.232 & -6.442 & -3.471 & -0.630 & -0.167 & -0.073 & -0.655 & -0.415 & -1.837\\
 Kurtosis & 44.684 & 396.572 & 356.572 & 12.145 & 21.741 & 45.938 & 9.759 & 12.355 & 41.134\\
 \midrule
 \multicolumn{10}{@{}l}{\textit{Panel B:1-minute returns}}
 \\
  Mean & -0.000 & 0.000 & -0.000 & -0.000 & -0.000 & -0.000 & -0.000 & -0.000 & -0.000\\
  Std.Dev & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.050 & 0.001 & 0.000 & 0.011 & 0.008 & 0.000 & 0.001\\
  Min & -0.000 & -0.005 & -2.200 & -0.013 & -0.002 & -0.038 & -0.118 & -0.012 & -0.012\\
  Max & 0.000 & 0.004 & 0.906 & 0.011 & 0.001 & 0.033 & 0.121 & 0.009 & 0.011\\
  Skewness & -0.000 & -0.436 & -13.229 & -0.137 & -0.071 & -0.033 & 0.155 & -0.122 & -0.095\\
  Kurtosis & 1.017 & 13.434 & 665.225 & 7.421 & 33.709 & -0.418 & 60.108 & 25.359 & 4.829\\
 \midrule
 \multicolumn{10}{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}{\textit{Note: n = 6000 observations, Std.Dev is the standard deviation, Min and Max are the minimum and maximum of the timeseries. EUR/USD and JPY/USD are neglected because of...}}
 \end{tabular*}
 \end{table}
 \end{document}
```

---

Here is an alternative using a slightly larger font size:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=30mm, right=30mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}
\caption{Descriptive statistics for hourly and minute returns of the timeseries.} \label{tab:title}
 \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l
                              S[table-format=-2.3]
                              S[table-format=3.3]
                              S[table-format=3.3]
                              *{6}{S[table-format=-2.3]}@{}
                              }
  \toprule
   & {USDT} & {PAX} & {DGX} & {PAXG} & {DAI} & {WBTC} & {AMPL} & {BTC} & {LTC}\\
   \midrule
   \multicolumn{10}{l}{\textit{Panel A:1-hour returns}}
   \\
   Mean & -0.000 & -0.000 & 0.000 & -0.000 & -0.000 & 0.000 & -0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 \\ 
   Std.Dev & 0.000 & 0.005 & 0.033 & 0.004 & 0.000 & 0.040 & 0.018 & 0.010 & 0.015\\
  Min & -0.004 & -0.205 & -1.156 & -0.045 & -0.009 & -0.750 & -0.228 & -0.129 & -0.341\\
  Max & 0.005 & 0.114 & 0.906 & 0.030 & 0.008 & 0.583 & 0.107 & 0.117 & 0.168\\
  Skewness & 1.232 & -6.442 & -3.471 & -0.630 & -0.167 & -0.073 & -0.655 & -0.415 & -1.837\\
 Kurtosis & 44.684 & 396.572 & 356.572 & 12.145 & 21.741 & 45.938 & 9.759 & 12.355 & 41.134\\
 \midrule
 \multicolumn{10}{@{}l}{\textit{Panel B:1-minute returns}}
 \\
  Mean & -0.000 & 0.000 & -0.000 & -0.000 & -0.000 & -0.000 & -0.000 & -0.000 & -0.000\\
  Std.Dev & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.050 & 0.001 & 0.000 & 0.011 & 0.008 & 0.000 & 0.001\\
  Min & -0.000 & -0.005 & -2.200 & -0.013 & -0.002 & -0.038 & -0.118 & -0.012 & -0.012\\
  Max & 0.000 & 0.004 & 0.906 & 0.011 & 0.001 & 0.033 & 0.121 & 0.009 & 0.011\\
  Skewness & -0.000 & -0.436 & -13.229 & -0.137 & -0.071 & -0.033 & 0.155 & -0.122 & -0.095\\
  Kurtosis & 1.017 & 13.434 & 665.225 & 7.421 & 33.709 & -0.418 & 60.108 & 25.359 & 4.829\\
 \bottomrule
 \end{tabular*}\smallskip
 
 \itshape Note: n = 6000 observations, Std.Dev is the standard deviation, Min and Max are the minimum and maximum of the timeseries. EUR/USD and JPY/USD are neglected because of...
 \end{table}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: +1. If you change `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}` to `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}`, you can get by with `\small` instead of `\footnotesize`. Also, consider rplacing the \hline` directives  with `\midrule`.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of the left over `\hline`s. Regarding your other suggestion about decreasing the value of `\tabcolsep` while using  a `\small` font size: If I apply the suggested changes, I end up with the following output https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRnfV.png which shows a very uneven distribution of horizontal padding. I therefore added an alternative MWE in which I moved the notes part outside of the tabular.